Tile shower adhesive cracking
I am trying to replace a section of 6x6 tiles in the tub/shower. I replaced damaged portions of the backer board and caulked all the joints with DAP kwik seal adhesive caulk except where the backer meets the tub. Then I used fiber mesh at all the joints and at the tub, and applied Daltile's Dal-Stick Acrylic Ceramic floor & wall tile adhesive (I assumed the the Dal-Stick would work like thinset).  Where the tub meets the backer there is about a 1/4" gap. I bridged the gap with the fiber and pushed it in the gap a little to give a thicker area on the tub for the Dal-Stick to bond. I also used the adhesive to try to fill in a spot where I had to patch the backer. Both of these areas cracked. Also, there are places in the corners that are cracked but the Dal-Stick wasn’t all that thick in those areas.

What should I do now? Fill the cracks with more Dal-Stick? Fill the cracks with Dap Kwik seal adhesive? Fill the cracks with a silicone sealer? Tear it out and start again?

My plan once this is figured out is to paint on Redgard. I’ve seen folks use 2 coats, but I was planning to do a couple of extra coats.

Any issues using extra coats of Redgard?

Then I was going to use the Dal-Stick to install the tiles. The trowel I bought is a 1/4”x1/4”x1/4”.

Will that work or should I use a 1/4”x3/4”x1/4”. The Dal-Stick container calls for a V groove trowel for glazed tile but everything else I’ve see calls for a notched trowel. Considering the cracking in the corners, I'm concerned the Dal-Stick is very sensitive to cracking.

Once the tile is installed I have Mapei grout for the tile joints, and 100% silicone for the corners and between the tub and tile.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Did you fill the tub before caulking the fiber gap between tub and backer?

No,I didn't fill the tub. However, the tub was never filled so I don't think that's what caused the cracks.  I thought I was supposed to do that when caulking the tile at the end.

The Dal-Stick is an adhesive and not a filler.  It will crack when applied too thick.  (Personally I would not use it in a wet location, but it is approved for tub and showers.)
If the cracks are superficial, just do your Redguard. (I think more than 3 coats is overkill.) Then when dry apply your tile.  Your trowel selection is a bit agressive I would use a 3/16 1/4 1/4 V notch trowel.
Be sure you have the proper grout for the size grout lines.  (Over 1/8" requires sanded grout. Under 1/8" requires unsanded.)

That's for your response! Some  cracks are superficial but at the tub they are deep.  If they can be filled, is there a filler you recommend?

It's not critical and depends on how deep "deep" is.  A pic will help a lot in determining more here.  I have used a polyurethane caulk to seal the gap between the wall boards and the tub.

Here are 3 pictures.  https://imgur.com/a/7ApDs4f    One is before applying the adhesive, 2 are after. The cracks are probably only 1/16". At the tub, they probably go through to the fiber but it's hard to tell.  The adhesive is probably 1/8" to 1/4" thick there.  Could I fill this crack and gap with the tub with polyurethane caulk?  Also, A small piece of gray cement board was added in the corner. It is a little thinner than the adjacent brown backer board. Will filler stick to the adhesive?

Pictures definitely tell a story.   In truth, after seeing what you have, I have very little confidence in a good outcome.   The "brown backer board"  Is old water resistant drywall with the paper facing torn off.  In my opinion it should be replaced.  I now feel the entire tub surround should be torn out and recovered in cement backer board.  Otherwise in the short future you will be tearing it out anyway.

Thanks for looking at the pictures. Is the issue that filling/patching and using red gard on the old backer won’t hold and the tiles will fall off? We were really hoping for health related reasons to get a few more years before having the bathroom redone professionally. My main concern is keeping water and possible mold out of the wall so if the issue is just cosmetic, we can live with that, but we don’t want a water related problem. The old backer that remains didn't have any water damage if that makes a difference.

The issue has nothing to do with cosmetics.  I don't have confidence that water can be kept from getting into the old backer and deteriorating it.   That is a bigger issue than the tile falling off. It's the wall board turning to mush and the wall falling apart.

I understand.  Thanks for all your help and your quick replys.  I've been slow to respond because I've been weighing my options. I'll be reaching out to a local repair person for help.  Thanks again.
